# Losing part of a url while passing it from powershell to batch

Tags: php, powershell, batch-file

I've got some powershell that connects to my server and returns an address to be passed to a batch file.

This batch file is a requirement, as it's an HTA/Batch Hybrid that allows me to run a created UI for the project. The URL is being passed as an iframe source to load some results from the server.

I have a variable `$content` in powershell, which equals `http://example.com/selectMultiple.php?choice=[{"id":51,"p":100},{"id":52,"p":94}]` (Slightly modified to protect my server address)

I then launch the batch file, while passing that `$content` variable to it like this

```
"Launching $content"
Start-Process "files\hybrid.bat" "$content"
```

In the batch file I have some code that echo's the value that was passed to it.

```
set "link=%~1"
echo %link%
```

But after being passed, some of the variable is trimmed. This echos `http://example.com/selectMultiple.php?choice` - which leads me to believe that there is something with the `=` sign that is breaking the string.

I've tried urldecode methods in powershell and from my server (php) and neither fixed the issue.

I am at a loss here and would much appreciate any help resolving this issue./

(I tagged PHP as well, to show that I do have the ability to work with the code that is returning the URL)

Comment: cant you get rid of batch file and do stuff with powershell directly? can you dump text to a file and read it in the batch file (as a workaround)? can you save text to env variable and read it in the batch file?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I can't get rid of the batch file, I'm using it as an HTA/Batch Hybrid. The url is being passed to basically open an HTA and load an iframe with the URL. I could probably dump it to a file as a workaround, but I feel like that would be a slower approach and for this application I need to to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Windows command prompt takes the `=`-sign as a token separator just like the space; perhaps it helps when you use `set "link=%*"` in your batch file as you are passing only the link anyway...

Comment: `Start-Process "files\hybrid.bat" """$content"""` note tripled double quotes.

Comment: @JosefZ That did it. I didn't think it would have to be quotes multiple times. I never would have thought of that ^.^ Could you please post as an answer and explain why this needs to be done?

Comment: A different way on the batch side is to get not a singe argument `%1` but to catch all with `%*` the equal sign is still in there.

Comment: @LotPings I think this is a bad idea, as I may (or anyone else with a similar situation) may need to pass multiple variables to the batch file (Meaning it could be less future-proof if you are unsure if this condition exists). But still a valid answer and you should post an answer :)

Comment: Then try to quote (`""`) the whole URL and state `%~1` rather than `%1` in the batch file to remove the quotes...

Comment: @aschipfl I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. My batch file already had %~1 and the whole thing is quoted in the powershell. Either way it's solved now thanks to JosefZ.

Comment: I meant to pass the URL over to the batch file including surrounding `""`, because when the `=` appears in between quotes, it is no longer recognised as a token separator (same is true for spaces); anyway, I think this is exactly what JosefZ does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Start-Process "files\hybrid.bat" """$content"""
```

Note that `$content` variable contains characters (e.g. `=` and `,`) which are treated as [**parameter delimiters**](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters) in batch scripting:

> Delimiters separate one parameter from the next - they split the
>   command line up into words.
>
> Parameters are most often separated by spaces, but any of the
>   following are also valid delimiters:
>
> - Comma (,)
> - Semicolon (;)
> - Equals (=)
> - Space ( )
> - Tab (     )

The called batch (see `set "link=%~1"` command) strips the first supplied parameter from enclosing double quotes in the right way. Hence, you need to pass the string from `$content` variable [enclosed in double quotes from powershell](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html#quotes). Use doubled inner double quotes as follows:

```
#                                ↓            ↓ string delimiters are not supplied
Start-Process "files\hybrid.bat" """$content"""
#                                 ↑↑        ↑↑  escaped inner double quotes are supplied
```

> Double-Quoted Strings (`"`)
>
> When you enclose a string in double quotation marks, any variable
>   names in the string such as `"$myVar"` will be replaced with the
>   variable's value when the command is processed. … **Any embedded
>   double quotes can be escaped using the grave-accent as `` `" `` or
>   doubled (replace `"` with `""`)**.